# Can't use anything but 0 to pad a number in println

Tags: rust, rustup

I am new to Rust, hence I am experimenting with various argument when passing to `println!` macro.
when I try the following code I can compile it successfully.

```
println! (" let the world be in peace {number:0width$} ",number = 1.1414, width = 9);
```

the out is as follows :

```
let the world be in peace 0001.1414
```

hence my understanding is based on value of `width`, the value of `0` is added as padding to output. But When I try the following code to add `1` as padding, it leads to a Compilation Error:

```
println! ("let me know {number:1width$}",number = 1.1414, width = 9);
```

The Compilation Error stack is as follows:

```
    error: invalid format string: expected `'}'`, found `'$'`
  --> print_statements.rs:25:42
   |
25 |     println! ("let me know {number:1width$}",number = 1.1414, width = 9);
   |                            -             ^ expected `}` in format string
   |                            |
   |                            because of this opening brace
   |
   = note: if you intended to print `{`, you can escape it using `{{`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Am I missing something?
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the naming convention may unfortunately make it seem that `1width` (or any number in front of `width`) is valid, this isn't true. The 0 is a [specific number formatting flag](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#sign0) for padding a number with 0 instead of spaces like normal.

It may be helpful to think about the purpose of width for why this is the case. Width ensures a value takes up at least a specific number of characters (useful for aligning multiple lines) by filling up the *remaining* space with a filler character **that does not change the value of what's printed**. 0 is given as an additional choice versus spaces because adding 0s to the beginning/end of a number does not change the value, but adding 1s completely changes the printed value in a way that is unpredictable (based on the number length).

That said, rust provides [fill/alignment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#fillalignment) as a way to specify the character used as padding for width. Using that, your `println!` becomes the following:

```rust
println!("let me know {number:1>width$}", number = 1.1414, width = 9);
```